Using GithubApp to create teams and repositories via terraform gives 403 error
I am trying to create teams and repositories via terraform however I get the following error:
Error: POST https://api.github.com/orgs/MyOrgName/repos: 403 Resource not accessible by integration []

I have created an Github App on organization. The Github App has these permissions:


Terraform setups look like below:
provider "github" {
  owner = "MyOrgName"
  app_auth {
    id              = "1111"   #GITHUB_APP_ID
    installation_id = "222222" #GITHUB_APP_INSTALLATION_ID
    pem_file        = file("private-key.pem")#GITHUB_APP_PEM_FILE
  }
}

resource "github_team" "all_teams" {
  name           = "All Teams"
  description    = "Parent team for all other teams. Give this team access to your repo to have a transparent code ecosystem."
  privacy        = "closed"
  parent_team_id = null
}

module "repo_terraform-aws-ec2" {
  source = "../repository"

  name        = "terraform-aws-ec2"
  description = "Terraform module for EC2 servers"
  auto_init   = false

  has_issues = true

  permission_admin_teams = [data.github_team.all_teams]
  permission_write_teams = [data.github_team.all_teams]
  branch_protection = {
    require_signed_commits = false
  }
}

Does anyone know what setup/permissions I am missing?
